# Is this fourier even?

Tags: fourier-series

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2} & [0,\pi] \\
-\frac{3\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}, & (\pi,2\pi)
\end{cases}
$$[image]

Is it right to compute only $a_n \text{ and } a_0$ coefficient for fourier series because $f(x)$ is even for fourier? How can I proove it since $f(x)!=f(-x)$

Comment: How did you conclude that $f(x) \ne f(-x)$? Please show us the steps. (This is a common mistake, but if you show the steps I can point out the mistake).

Comment: From visual inspection, we have $f(x)=f(2\pi-x)$. And $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)=0$

Comment: fourier $b_n$ == 0 too?

Comment: @Parhs Yes, that is true for all even functions.

Comment: I guess that I did not quite understand the question yet.

Comment: @mike Why? In Fourier series of even functions, $b_n = 0$, so only the $a_n$ have to be calculated.

Comment: the question is if we can conclude that $b_n =0$ without calculating it. and since domain isnt at -pi,pi how can we tell

Comment: @M.Vinay. I just realized the convention. By the way, I am not math-majored.

Comment: @M.Vinay I know that b_n is zero for even function but because this isnt even at x=0  but $f(x)=f(2π−x)$  me an other students had trouble with that.

Comment: @Parhs. Since $f(x)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic. $f(x)=f(2\pi+x)$. The definition of $f(x)$ showed the symmetry $f(x)=f(2\pi-x)$. So we have $f(-x)=f(2\pi+(-x))=f(2\pi-x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @Parhs One way to see this symmetry is set $x=2\pi-y$ and $g(y)=f(x)$. Then you can prove that $g(y)=f(y)$.

Comment: so is it safe to say $b_n=0$ and for $a_n$ calculate $2 \int_0^{pi}f(x)dx$ ?

Comment: ok it is becoming more clear. The problem was that I heard other students saying that teacher told that it isnt even and that they have found a $b_n$ after many computations

Comment: @mike You should just write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $2\pi$-periodic function $f(x)$ defined as:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2} & x\in [0,\pi] \\
-\frac{3\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}, & x\in(\pi,2\pi)
\end{cases}$$

We can calculate
$$f(2\pi-x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{2\pi-x}{2} & x\in [\pi,2\pi] \\
-\frac{3\pi}{4}+\frac{2\pi-x}{2}, & x\in (0,\pi)
\end{cases}$$

$$ =
\begin{cases}
\frac{-3\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2} & x\in [\pi,2\pi] \\
+\frac{1\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}, & x\in (0,\pi)
\end{cases}$$

Thus we proved
$$f(2\pi-x)=f(x)\text{   (1)}$$.

Since for $2\pi$-periodic function $f(-x)$ we have
 $$f(-x)= f((-x)+2\pi)=f(2\pi-x)\text{   (2)}$$

Combining (1) and (2), we proved
$$f(x)= f(-x)$$.

Thus the coefficients $b_n$ that go with $\sin(2nx)$ are zero.